# How to write the rendered content into a file

Tags: file, symfony

I want to get the content rendered, e.g. `$this->render('ProBundle:Default:view.html.twig', array('data' => $data));`, and write it into a file.

I've already created a file class:

```
<?php

namespace Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File as SymfonyFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="file")
 */
class File
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Constraints\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Constraints\NotNull
     * @Constraints\DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var SymfonyFile
     * @Constraints\File(maxSize=1048060)
     */
    private $filesystemFile;

    /**
     * @Constraints\NotNull
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\Convocation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $convocation;

    function __construct(SymfonyFile $file, $name)
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime;
        $this->setFilesystemFile($file);
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    function setFilesystemFile(SymfonyFile $file)
    {
        $this->filesystemFile = $file;
    }

    function getFilesystemFile()
    {
        return $this->filesystemFile;
    }
}
```

and a service:

```
<?php

namespace Pro\ConvocationBundle\Service;

use Frosas\Error;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\ConvocationFile as FileEntity;

class ConvocationFile
{
    private $dir;

    function __construct($dir)
    {
        $this->dir = $dir;
    }

    function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (($entity = $args->getEntity()) instanceof FileEntity) {
            $filesystemFilePath = $this->getFilesystemPath($entity);
            $filesystemFile = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($filesystemFilePath);
            $entity->setFilesystemFile($filesystemFile);
        }
    }

    function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (($entity = $args->getEntity()) instanceof FileEntity) {
            $this->saveToFilesystem($entity);
        }
    }

    function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (($entity = $args->getEntity()) instanceof FileEntity) {
            if ($entity->getFilesystemFile()->getPathname() !== $this->getFilesystemPath($entity)) {
                $this->saveToFilesystem($entity);
            }
        }
    }

    function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (($entity = $args->getEntity()) instanceof FileEntity) {
            $ok = @unlink($entity->getFilesystemFile());
            if (! $ok) throw Error::createExceptionFromLast();
        }
    }

    private function saveToFilesystem(FileEntity $file)
    {
        $filesystemFile = $file->getFilesystemFile();
        if ($filesystemFile === null) throw new \InvalidArgumentException("No file given");
        if (! $filesystemFile->isFile()) throw new \InvalidArgumentException("File is not a file");

        $path = $this->getFilesystemPath($file);
        $filesystemFile->move(dirname($path), basename($path));
    }

    private function getFilesystemPath(FileEntity $file)
    {
        return "$this->dir/{$file->getId()}";
    }
}
```

and in the configuration file:

```
pro_convocation.convocation_file:
    class: Pro\ConvocationBundle\Service\File
    arguments: [%kernel.root_dir%/var/files]
    tags:
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad}
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist}
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate}
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postRemove}
```

So I guessed I could call the service and create the file:

```
$newContent = $this->get('templating')->render('ProConvocationBundle:Default:view.html.twig', array('data' => $data));

$this->get('pro_convocation.convocation_file')->postPersist($newContent);
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Pro\ConvocationBundle\Service\File::postPersist() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, string given
```

The `postPersist` accepts an event object as an argument, and not the content to write. So I'm now a bit confused about how to create the new file. Any idea?

Comment: Because when you call `postPersist` you are sending a rendered string and should be an object instance of `LifecycleEventArgs`. If you have the entity object I suggest to send the object and `templating` service to the `postPersist` then do the rendering and passing to save file in that function

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but you are using `$this->render()`.  That will return a `Response` object.  If you want the string, use `$this->renderView()`.  I assume you don't want to write the Response object to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to use the *ConvocationFile* class as a service. It's a service but it's not meant to be called this way. That's why the class should be inside an *EventListener* folder in your bundle like the Symfony2 convention says:

```
\src\Pro\ConvocationBundle\EventListener\ConvocationFile.php
```

If you want to call this service manually, as long as it's an event listener, you have to dispatch an event that your listener can catch.

So, you should try with something like:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;

$arguments = array('my_stuff');

$evm = new EventManager();
$evm->dispatchEvent(Events::postUpdate, $arguments);
```

Otherwise you can define a service that handles your files saving them to the file-system and making your event listener and your controller use it.

For further information:

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Thanks Francesco, I'll have a look.